# subscribe to an array python ros

Tags: python, pyqt, ros

It's my first time using python in ROS and I'm stuck with the syntax, I want to make a python subscribe to a 1D array that I have already published using C++ and I also want to access the element of this array and use it to display a map on a window using PyQt, but I can't access the data inside the array because I don't know the syntax
there is an error in line 33 (`msg.(i+j)==1`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys 
from mainw import Ui_Form
#Subscriber 
from std_msgs.msg import MultiArrayDimension
from std_msgs.msg import Int32MultiArray 
import rospy

class main(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        for i in range(0,20):
            for j in range(0,20):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem())

    def callback(msg):
        for i in range(0,19):
            for j in range(0,19):
                if(msg.(i+j)==1) 
                    self.tableWidget.item(i,j).setBackground(QColor(170, 0, 0))

                else if(data.data==2)
                    self.tableWidget.item(i, j).setBackground(QColor(170, 0, 0))


def TwoDMap():
    rospy.init_node('TwoDMap', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("array", Int32MultiArray, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TwoDMap()        
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Start with a smaller example without Qt. There are numerous problems in your code, the one in line 33 is just the first one that is reported: `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` is never executed because `rospy.spin()` doesn't return, `else if` is not valid Python, `data` does not exist in `callback()` and has the wrong type for a comparison with `2`, `callback()` does not exist in `TwoDMap()`, `self` does not exist in `callback()`.
For line 33: You want something like `msg.data[i * stride + j]`, where you get the stride from `msg.layout`.

Comment: I justified your code snippet indentation, hope that be your correct code snippet. else, consider an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Int32MultiArray message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int32MultiArray.html), you should have change like this:

```
if msg.data[i+j] == 1:
    # do something

elif msg.data[i+j] == 2:
    # do something else
```

Also your `.callback()` method in the class hasn't `self` argument, and you have some mistakes in methods call. Thus, your code will be as the following:

```
class Main(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        rospy.Subscriber("array", Int32MultiArray, self.callback)

        for i in range(0,20):
            for j in range(0,20):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem())

    def callback(self, msg):
        for i in range(0,19):
            for j in range(0,19):
                if msg.data[i+j] == 1: 
                    self.tableWidget.item(i,j).setBackground(QColor(170, 0, 0))

                elif msg.data[i+j] == 2:
                    self.tableWidget.item(i, j).setBackground(QColor(170, 0, 0))            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('TwoDMap', anonymous=True)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Main()
    obj.show()
    app.exec_() 
    rospy.spin()
```

Comment: it didn't work at fist because `obj = Main()`   `obj.twoDMap()`  had to be after `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` and i also had to delete `rospy.spin` as the code goes into a loop and doesn't show the at all, but now I can't properly receive the message from TwoDMap topic, any idea how can I solve this ?